# Making an empty matrix

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

How do I make an empty matrix with K rows? Then how would I add something to that array by entering it into that specific row? I'm asking so that I can find the mean of each row after I have organized the values for a k-means algorithm so I can set new centroids.

```
Clabel = []
Cvalue = []
clusters = [] #This is what I want to have as a matrix
x = numpy.mean(df[:,0:d], axis = 1)
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    temp = []
    for j in range(k):
        dist = numpy.linalg.norm(ids[j] - x[i])
        temp.append(dist)
    v = numpy.argmin(temp)
    w = numpy.amin(temp)
    Clabel.append(v+1)
    Cvalue.append(w)
    clusters = numpy.concatenate(([Clabel],[Cvalue]), axis = 0)
```

The issue is that the way I have done it, it makes 2 rows. First row is the labels for the clusters and the second is all the values I have found. Is there a better way to organize this? It currently returns this as a matrix

```
[[1.    1.    1.    3.    3.    1.    2.    3.   ]
 [0.325 0.15  0.1   0.325 0.425 0.3   0.1   0.45 ]]
```

What I want it to do is this.

```
[[0.325, 0.15, 0.1, 0.3]
 [0.1]
 [0.325, 0.425, 0.45]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize `clusters`?  You set it later with the concatenate; that completely over writes anything you assigned at the start.  But if you want to add to `clusters`, what you are doing with `temp` and `Clabel` lists is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Numpy allows you to use select based on condition.

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
a = np.array([[1.,    1.,    1.,    3.,    3.,    1.,    2.,    3.   ], \
[0.325, 0.15 , 0.1 ,  0.325, 0.425, 0.3,   0.1,   0.45 ]])

b = []
for val in set(a[0]):
    b.append(a[1][a[0]==val])
pprint(b)
```

Original answer:

Since you already using numpy, and if you know the dimension of the matrix, aka, both numbers of row and column.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.zeros(shape=(2,2))

m[0] = [1,2]
m[1] = [3,4]
```

Hope this helps.